# group chat in flutter using firebase with a twist

Tags: android, database, firebase, flutter

Disclaimer: I have never worked with firebase or any other DB so my idea is pretty rough and I will be glad if u correct me in some of my assumptions. Also this is my first question on StackOverflow so I hope it will be detailed enough.

I am currently working on my project which is basically a group chat in flutter using firebase, where I should be able to create a new group chat(create a new DB in firestore) trough the app, let other ppl join(assign them to the new group chat DB).

The twist: If I send a message to the group chat I want other ppl to see a pop-up saying: "do you accept this message", no=> doesn't show / yes=> Shows the message but deletes it for others.

This app is nothing but my idea of how to confirm my theory and also learn a little bit more about both flutter and firebase, so please do not mind if it's useful or not.

Assumption: Each groupchat has it's own DB (Can I create a DB in firestore trough app / send request to?)
Question: Can I assign a specific ID to each message and choose and further edit who is going to be able to see the message trough the app(app_instance_1"I accepted the message so only I and sender can see it")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a great article for making a Flutter chat app: https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-chat-app-in-flutter-with-firebase-888b6222fe20. If you need more detail or help just write a comment.

About your assumption. Each app usually is connected to one database, and within the database, you can have separate documents to hold each group chat. You can also set up documents for each individual user to save the chats that only they can see. Within documents, you add collections that hold your data.